# RelativeLayout-LayoutParams cannot be cast to FrameLayout-LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add images dynamically because imageview sources arechangeable also image counts are changeable.

```
public class MatchingGame extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG = "Chic";
    RelativeLayout rLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "matchinggame OnCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(rLayout);
        Log.d(TAG, "mx");
       // rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        Log.d(TAG, "mxx");
        rLayout.setLayoutParams(rLayParams);
        Log.d(TAG, "mmx");
      ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
       img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        img1.setTag(1);
        Log.d(TAG, "qx");
        rLayout.addView(img1);
        Log.d(TAG, "mqqx");
        rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
      //  rLayout.setLayoutParams(rLayParams);
        ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.b3_1);
        img1.setTag(2);
        rLayout.addView(img2);


    }

}
```

But I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

It is about this line i guess

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

I need put left center an image, andto  other side, other images so i need align parent and also size rule.

But it gives errors.

I have a layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    tools:context=".games.MatchingGame">



</RelativeLayout>
```

Do I need this layout? Because I create layout dynamically already.

I tried putting this static layout also, tried making with `findviewbyid` but always same errors.

I can see images without `setlayoutparams` method. But of course, without any rules so all images are on left corner top.

Comment: Check the messages on your other account.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "matchinggame OnCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(rLayout);
        Log.d(TAG, "mx");
       // rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

        rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);

        rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
       // rLayout.setLayoutParams(rLayParams);

      ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
       img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        img1.setTag(1);
        rLayout.addView(img1,rLayParams);

        //todo burda for olacak ona gore rlayparams degisecek

       rLayParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rLayParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
       // rLayout.setLayoutParams(rLayParams);
        ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.b3_1);
        img2.setTag(2);
        int i=2;
        img2.setId(R.id.img11);
        rLayout.addView(img2,rLayParams1);

        rLayParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rLayParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.img11);
        // rLayout.setLayoutParams(rLayParams);
        ImageView img3 = new ImageView(this);
        img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.b3_1);
        img3.setTag(3);
        rLayout.addView(img3,rLayParams2);

    }
```

I solved like this. Creating different relativelayoutparams for each image(becayse they have different rules) and

instead of this

```
 // rLayout.setLayoutParams(rLayParams);
```

i created this

```
rLayout.addView(img1,rLayParams);
```

and it worked.